# How to group and apply class for specific <li> within <ul> based on li:child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Please find my `ul li` here, This `li` is working for horizontal tab using a bootstrap tab. I'm trying to apply a class; when the 2nd and 3rd `li` have the class `active`, I want to apply a style class on the 1st `li`. simlarly for next 3 `li` and rest also. I've tried with jquery but didn't succeed.

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav-tabs">
  <li class="side-menu-grp"><a href="#">Group One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">List One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">List Two</a></li>

  <li class="side-menu-grp"><a href="#">Group Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">List One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">List Two</a></li>

  <li class="side-menu-grp"><a href="#">Group Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">List One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">List Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've added formatting but I still don't know what you're asking

Comment: Please post jquery code you have tried. You may also create http://jsfiddle.net and post a link to it.

Comment: When can the `active` class change? You need to intercept that moment.

Comment: Hi, Thanks please find my JsFiddle Link here http://jsfiddle.net/hLMzU/ . Here I want when u hover on the list the specific group should be highlight and when u click any list item respective group should be active.

Comment: In this bootstrap TAB, when u click on the list class="active" is added on <li>, how can I find the respective Group <li> element to add some class there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you want:

```
$('.active').prev('.side-menu-grp').addClass('class');
```

It selects the elements with class `active` (the `li`s if you don't reuse the class) and locates the first previous sibling element with class `side-menu-grp` and add the class what you want to it.